# Simplest way to set up a web server that can handle SOAP requests?

Tags: python, web-services, networking, soap

Simplest way to set up a web server that extends a web service that can handle SOAP requests?

I'm not looking to set up a Django framework but a simple python application that can handle SOAP requests. I looked around the web and I came up with so many available options that I'm confused as to how I should approach this. Some of these options were apache with mod-wsgi, or JAX-WS.

I have a device that sends out SOAP requests and I want a simple lightweight non-scalable web server that can handle them for development purposes.

Handle them as in dump the requests to console.

Comment: What do you mean by "handle them"? Dump the request to console? Proxy the request somewhere else? Return a meaningful response based on the request?

Comment: Dump the request to console.

Comment: Then you can just use [bottle](http://bottlepy.org) to quickly set up a server, since SOAP requests are essentially HTTP requests. Note that you will most likely have to return a valid, generic response that your device expects.

Comment: Can I use bottle for that purpose as well?